# Является ли выражение "планы на будущее" плеоназмом?

Tags: общие-вопросы, плеоназм

Всё предложение: "Планы на будущее великие"

Является ли в данном случае "планы на будущее" плеоназмом? Ведь как планы могут быть на прошлое?

Однако, в Большом толковом словаре в определении слова [перспектива](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0&all=x) есть в конце строчка "виды, планы на будущее".

Тогда возникает вопрос — можно ли считать это выражение плеоназмом или это зависит от контекста?

Answer (score 2):

Не думаю. *На будущее* — так говорят про длительный период, который будет относительно не скоро. Например:
*Сейчас у меня нет времени, но в будущем [когда-то] планирую этим заняться.*

А планы могут быть и на ближайшее время: на завтра, на вечер, а также на сейчас (это уж точно будущим не назовёшь).